# How do I securely push SPA client side logs to AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: security, single-page-application, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless

I am trying to push client side logs from a static SPA to AWS Cloudwatch, is there a secured way to do so?
Even if I design a server-less endpoint e.g. API gateway to capture these logs, where would I be able to store the security credentials so it's not exposed on the client side?

Thank you.

Comment: You would design an API that does not require security credentials, and does some validation that the data being sent are logs before passing the data to Cloudwatch. It will always be possible for someone to send you fake logs. That cannot be fixed.